# Running ASP file directly on your browser without typing into url

Tags: asp-classic

I'm currently new to asp.
I have just started running ASP file and the problem is every time I run an ASP file I have to enter the Path through url in browser.

```
example : http://localhost/MyWeb/test.asp
```

Is there any quick way of testing the ASP pages on browser.
I have created a Test server in Adobe Dreamweaver and able to run ASP pages via Dreamweaver.

But I want to run ASP files just by double Clicking on it.
Is there any way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is not directly possible.

What you **can** do is write a batch file, call it for example "DisplayPage.bat" and with such code:

```
set str=%1
set str=%str:C:\inetpub\wwwroot=http://localhost/MyWeb%
set str=%str:\=/%
start IEXPLORE.EXE %str%
REM pause
```

This is assuming your root web folder is "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" if not change to your root folder path.

Now having this follow these steps:

1. Right click any `.asp` file and choose "Open with"
2. In the menu select "Choose default program..."
3. Browse to the batch file you created above and confirm. Tick the "Always use the selected program to run this kind of file" to make it permanent.

This will cause double clicking to open the clicked file in Internet Explorer, pointing to localhost.

The above steps are for Windows 7 but can be achieved easily for any OS.

If something goes wrong with the process you can remove the "REM" from the last line so the batch file pause and show what went wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You can use includes

there are two types of includes File and Virtual read more at http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_incfiles.asp

Comment: This is totally non relevant to this question.